# Does "LINQ to DQL" exist?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, dql, documentum

If LINQ-to-SQL overcomes the object-relational impedance mismatch of a .NET application talking to a SQL Server database...

If I want to build a .NET MVC UI, where my model queries a Documentum CMS database...

**Is there a LINQ to DQL (Documentum Query Language) library  ? ...**

... that will help me overcome the object-relational impedance mismatch of talking to Documentum?

I am working on a project where a .NET web-application that pulls content from a Documentum 6.5 content management system is going to be re-built.

The .NET web-application will be .NET MVC and will be built as a self-standing application.

The team building the .NET application should ideally not have to learn the intricacies of Documentum and for an interface build, and a Documentum learning course is probably overkill and would probably exceed the project timeframe by 300%-400%.

So before I start trying to start calling up EMC, has anyone heard of anything like this?  I thought the idea of "LINQ to DQL" would be a logical step.  I have never worked with Documentum although I have worked with ECM before and understand the concepts.  I know that Documentum is traditionally *nix based, Java, Apache (Tomcat) but that shouldn't stop me querying it from a .NET application, similar to SQL. And if we take it that far, might as well look at LINQ for the querying mechanism...?

Comment: Hey, a long time has passed... do you know if there's a LINQ to DQL these days? Did you end up creating one? :)

Comment: No such thing exists unfortunately. Went with a different product.  You could optionally have documentum export data to xml and then use Linq to XML on that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem to exist, but you could implement your own Linq to DQL provider...

Check out this excellent series on [how to implement an IQueryable provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/pages/linq-links.aspx)

I used this tutorial to create a simple Linq to WMI provider (just for training, since [a much better one](http://www.codeplex.com/linq2wmi) already exists)